# Accessing Static Members of Static Members

Tags: c#, static

Consider the following classes

```
class A
{
public static int i;
}

class B
{
public static A a{get;}=new A();  // without new A(), B.A will be null
}
```

now,

**B.a** gives a new instance of A and since the variable "i" of class A is static, I can not access "i" through **B.a** i.e B.a.i is compile time error.

I understand that if I do like below,

```
class B
{
  static class A
  {
    static int i;
   }
}
```

then I could do B.A.i.

So my question is how could I access static members of a static member of a class? Is it possible at all and is there any other pattern that I can use.

Also note that making class "A" as static and having class "B" as

```
class B
{
public static A a{get;}
}
```

gives a compile time error that "**static type cannot be used as return type**".

Comment: If you want to get i, just do A.i. How is B even relevant here?

Comment: I know. Just wanted to know if that is possible. Trying to learn patterns actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `i` is static member of `A` you can access it directly like

```
class B
{
  public static A a {get;} = new A();  
  public int ii{get;} = A.i; 
}
```

Comment: Nice pattern. I could not think of it. But why is returning Static Type not allowed?

Comment: @dividedbyzero, it's the same as in posted answer.

Comment: But we can't do return A, if A is static.

Answer (score 0):

> how could I access static members of a static member of a class?

If something is a member of a class -- static or not static -- that means it's either a value or a reference to an *instance* of something.  Therefore, if you know you have an instance of a class but that class has static members itself, then just access those members statically:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static string Value { get; }
}

string x = MyClass.Value;
```

Comment: " if you know you have an instance of a class but that class has static members itself, then just access those members statically" how can I access the static member through instance of a class??

Comment: You don't...you just access it through the class itself, just like my example.

Comment: I understand that. My problem is accessing i through B.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instantiate a class to access it's static members.
Simply you can try :

```
int value = A.i;
```

If you need, you can add a static class too :

```
public static class A
{
public static int i;
}
```

and you can use anywhere in your code like :

```
int value = A.i;
```

Comment: I am looking to access A.i through class B.

Comment: class B{ int value = A.i; }

Comment: Good technique. But my concern is every time a property get increase in A , a line of code also needs to be added at B.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand, you need only this class B { A.i++;}

Comment: Or you can create a methode in the class b to increase A : classe B{ void increaseA{ A.i++;}}

Comment: Actually I meant if Class A adds another property say public static int j. Then I have to write one more line of code in B like int value2=A.j